# Materialized View data different from View with same source

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Data fetched MV is slightly different from data retrieved from view with exact same source sql. Data fetched from MV is inaccurate and inconsistent.

Also, under what circumstances would this data differ? I used NO CACHE NOLOGGING and there is no MV view logs as well.

I have Oracle 10g. Tried dropping and re-creating MV, no use. Fax is of VARCHAR2 data type.

MV is created off a view called BECRS. BECRS view consists of some rows, which are flattened in the MV by picking the max value.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MYROW
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTUSED    0 PCTFREE    10 INITRANS   2 MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (INITIAL 64K MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED PCTINCREASE      0 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
NOCACHE NOLOGGING NOCOMPRESS
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE
START WITH ...NEXT ...
WITH PRIMARY KEY AS 
SELECT B_ID || '.' || LANG_ID AS ID, 
       , COMP_ID
       , MAX(TRIM(PHONE_AREA_CODE)) AS PHONE_AREA_CODE
       , MAX(TRIM(BECRS.PHONE)) AS "PHONE"
       , MAX(TRIM(FAX_AREA_CODE)) AS FAX_AREA_CODE
       , MAX(TRIM(FAX)) AS FAX
...
FROM BECRS
GROUP BY SELECT B_ID, LANG_ID, COMP_ID
```

1. In selected instances, fax returned is NULL whereas there is actual fax
   data.
2. Now when I create a view with the exact same SELECT, I get the
   proper fax data (max of faxes)
3. When I query BECRS directly, I get all rows before flattening, and
       some rows have fax data, so max of that also returns correct fax.
4. This is not just with fax, it happens with other fields too.
5. One time, the MV returned fax which was non existent in the
       underlying source. After a few days (MV gets refreshed daily) this
       non existent fax disappeared from MV.

Comment: If the materialized view is only refreshed daily, it will return different results for any row that is modified during the day.  Are you certain that you're not just seeing the results of the materialized view showing the data as it existed at the time of refresh?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, sure. same inconsistent data still present today.. i test on MV, view with same sql as source, underlying source BECRS view multiple times each day, including today; point#5 in my question was detected just once, but other points are evident even today

Comment: I also manually refresh the MV manually before tests, so data should be consistent.